# Having type deduced class member variables

Tags: c++

I want to have a class variable, but I do not want/can write its type.

Here is an example.

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
    T t;
public:
    explicit Wrapper(T t) : t(t) {}

    void call() { t(); };
};

class Problem {
public:
    void test() {}

//    auto x = Wrapper([](auto x) {}); // 1.

//    auto y = Wrapper(&Problem::test); // 2.
//    Wrapper<void (Problem::*)()> y = Wrapper(&Problem::test); // 3.

//    static auto getter(){
//        return Wrapper(&Problem::test);
//    }
//    decltype(getter()) z = getter(); // 4.

};

int main() {
    auto x = Wrapper([] {});
    auto y = Wrapper(&Problem::test);

    Problem p;
}
```

I can declare x and y as variables in a function, but I want to have them as class variables.
For variant 1., it seems not even possible to have it in the class, because the lambda has a unique which can not be repeated.
For variant 2, it is in theory possible to make it working (3.) but this is a minimal example, I my real application the type is far more complex, so that I do not want to write it down.
4. was my try to make it working, but it does not work either.

Is it possible to have variables like x and y in a class?

Comment: Would `std::function` work for you?

Comment: @PaulSanders Where? I could use std::function in wrapper (but I would prefer not to change Wrapper), but how does it solve the problem?

Comment: @gerum It provides a type for the lbds

Comment: Macro: `#define Declare(var, init) decltype(init) var = init;`? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8bjsdWrWb) (won't work with lambda which produce unique type).

Comment: @Jarod42 Good hint, I had tries that which the lambda(which I would prefer), but if I dont use lambdas it is an ok-ish solution.

Comment: With C++20, you might do `decltype(Wrapper([](auto ) {})) x{{}};` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x5o9cEnjW).

Comment: @PaulSanders, you are right in combination with the macro it would be a solution without much writing.

Comment: @Jarod42 I must try that with my bigger example(which more type deduction involved), but that sounds like the solution I was searching for.

Comment: @Jarod42 That works, but it has the disadvantage, that you can not use member functions any more.

Comment: @PaulSanders The solution with the macro does not work in my case, because one of the arguments I have omitted for the example is a this argument (the object should get the surrounding class as argument)

Comment: Do you want to deduce the type of `x` and `y` from the type `T`?

Comment: @alfC I do not understand you question, I want to have a member variable where the type can be deduced, but I do not want to write it (or can, in case of lambda)

Comment: ok, but what is that type going to be based on?

Comment: @alfC based on the constructor arguments, like shown in the example. What else?

Comment: could be `T` itself. If you need to deduce any type information you need to use CTAD, as it name implies, contruction template argument deduction, in some form.

Answer (score 1):

The following allows for the `Wrapper` class member variables `x` and `y`. The compiler should optimize the lambda appropriately. The member function will dispatch using `std::function`. Does this accomplish the goal?

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
    T t;
public:
    explicit Wrapper(T t) : t(t) {}

    void call() {
        cout << "Wrapper called with " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
        t();
    };
};

class Problem {
public:
    void test() { }

    // Case 1: Lambda
    static constexpr auto l = []() { };
    Wrapper<decltype(l)> x{l};

    // Case 2: Pointer to member
    Wrapper<std::function<void()>> y{std::bind(&Problem::test, this)};
};

int main() {
    Problem p;
    p.x.call();
    p.y.call();

    // You need an object to invoke a pointer to member.
    // auto y = Wrapper(&Problem::test);
    // y.call(); // Fails to compile

    // This is how to use pointer to member.
    (&p)->Problem::test();
}
```

### Output

```
Wrapper called with N7Problem3$_0E
Wrapper called with NSt3__18functionIFvvEEE
```

Comment: May want to `#include <functional>` for completeness (for g++ 13)

Comment: Yes, I feel like `libstdc++` has partitioned the includes much more finely than `libc++`. I updated the answer.

Comment: `Wrapper` is a distraction from main problem. I guess just need to deduce the type of a none-static data member from its default value. I can prepare a relply if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This an example of [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), and perfectly works under C++20. With C++17 however, you'll need a CTAD guide:

```
template<typename T>
wrapper(T) -> wrapper<T>;
```

By the way, I would define the constructor to capture by rvalue and move it:

```
template<typename T>
struct wrapper{
    wrapper(T&& t_): t{std::move(t_)}{};
};

template<typename T>
wrapper(T&&) -> wrapper<T>;
```

On earlier versions this won't compile. But the `std::make_pair` technique can help:

```
template<typename T>
auto make_wrapper(T &&t) -> wrapper<T> {return {t};};

auto w = make_wrapper([]{});
```

Comment: Either I do not unterstand your answer, or you do not unterstand my question. For my class CTAD works fine, but I can you it in a class, because you can not delcare member variables as auto.

Comment: The way I read the question is that CTAD isn't the problem, but determining the member variable type is. You cannot deduce the member variable type given the initializer in, C++17 or C++20, deduction guideline or not...

Comment: @gerum Now I see. Modify 4. To  a constexpr static object instead of function.

Comment: @fabian it seems not like a yes/no question to me. It is rather a howto.